# How to Using Webdriver Selenium to get the value of “style” element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below HTML path for which I am trying to capture "Inbox" value but I am not able to find particular element in google chrome using Selenium Webdriver.

HTML Path :

```
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: white; text-align: left; width: 84px; height: 14px; padding-left: 1px; padding-top: 1px; left: 1px; top: 1px; background-color: rgb(102, 0, 153);">Inbox"

    <img src="/images/tridown.gif" style="position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 4px; top: 9px; left: 75px;">
</div>"Inbox"

<img src="/images/tridown.gif" style="position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 4px; top: 9px; left: 75px;">
</div>
```

I think left and top is unique identifer for Inbox dropdown, so can you please help us to write command to get "Inbox" value from above HTML

Comment: Could You format the HTML? It would be easier to read?

Comment: Can you post full code of html. What you have posted that is not in correct format.

Answer (score 13):

As Michas and Saritha G suggested, your HTML code is formatted correctly, but having said that. Please use this example below:

```
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: white; text-align: left; width: 84px; height: 14px; padding-left: 1px; padding-top: 1px; left: 1px; top: 1px; background-color: rgb(102, 0, 153);"></div>
```

If you want to retrieve the value for "style" attribute for the element above, you need to first locate this element:

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector("this element css selector here")
attributeValue = element.get_attribute("style")
```

Then attributeValue should have this following string "**position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: white; text-align: left; width: 84px; height: 14px; padding-left: 1px; padding-top: 1px; left: 1px; top: 1px; background-color: rgb(102, 0, 153)**;"

I am using Python as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but still...

I solved this using the **value_of_css_property()**. In my case, I need to wait a loader disappear. So I used this:

```py
loader = wrapper.find_element(By.ID, "loader_view")  
while loader.value_of_css_property('display') == 'block':  
    sleep(1)  
# do some stuff...
```